# Node Sequelize Followering/Following Relationship

Tags: node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

As the title states, i'm trying to figure out how to do a following/follower relationship in Sequelize. I'm more so trying to implement what i did in Rails into Node.

So heres the Ruby Code

InRelationship Model class file Ruby

```
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
```

In user model class file Ruby

```
# Relationships
has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
```

Now heres my attempt of translating this code into nodeJS Sequelize
User File - NodeJS Sequelize

```
 User.hasMany(models.Relationships, {
      as: "active_relatinships",
      foreignKey: "followerId"
    })
 User.hasMany(models.Relationships, {
      as: "passive_relatinships",
      foreignKey: "followingId"
    })
```

Rleationship File NodeJS Sequelize

```
 Relationships.belongsToMany(models.User, 
      {through: "active_relationships", as: "follower"})
 Relationships.belongsToMany(models.User, 
      {through: "passive_relationships", as: "followed"})
```

What am i doing wrong? This is the error i get when tryin to include in my Query

Unhandled rejection Error: Relationships (active_relationships) is not associated to User!

Here is my include query

```
    include: [
        {model: models.Areas, as: "current_area" }, 
        {model: models.VisitedAreas},
        {model: models.OnTheWays, include: [
          {model: models.Areas, as: "Area"}]},
        {model: models.Settings},
        {model: models.Pictures},
        {model: models.Relationships, as: "passive_relationships"},
        {model: models.Relationships, as: "active_relationships"}]
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065154/how-to-get-all-children-or-parents-in-a-many-to-many-association-if-one-model-re/72951602#72951602 There I show how to get both following and followed by users with clean queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea about this question! on my option:
you should use this.

```
   User.hasMany(models.Relationships, {foreignKey: "followerId"})
   include: [{model: models.Relationships}]
```

I write a demo about this question:

```
   User.hasMany(Money, {foreignKey: "followingId"});
   const result = await dbs.User.findAll({include: [{modedbs.Money}]});
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

This is my result:[image]

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am attempting to relate users to a model named relationships, and have an active relationship which is the user following and a passive relationship, which is other users following that user

Comment: @TravisDelly I'm so sorry!

Comment: BTW, I still think you shouldn't use as!